# aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb start with some errors

Tags: python, linux, gdb, embedded-linux, cross-compiling

When I use aaarch64-Linux-GNU-GDB debugger, there are some errors when aaarch64-Linux-GNU-GDB starts.

```
➜  gdb aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py", line 144, in auto_load_packages
    __import__(modname)
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/command/explore.py", line 756, in <module>
    Explorer.init_env()
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/command/explore.py", line 135, in init_env
    gdb.TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF : ReferenceExplorer,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF'
```

Python version information is as follows

```
➜  gdb python -V    
Python 2.7.17
➜  gdb which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: What is the version of `aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb`? If it's older then 2018, then that explains why `TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF` isn't found, because it didn't exist back then. But why would this gdb use the python libs of your standard gdb?

Comment: `GNU gdb (Linaro_GDB-2017.05) 7.12.1.20170417-git
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>`

Comment: I used the `sudo apt-get instal gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu `   command to install the cross tool chain. Its own GDB is version 7.12 by default.

Comment: Which version of python libs should arch 64-Linux-GNU-GDB use

Comment: I thought that a cross-gdb would install its python stuff in its own directory, but apparently that is not the case. Seems to be a bad idea to share them, and I'm kinda surprised that not more people have problems like this. If you don't use the `explore` command, you could just remove the `explore.py` file.

Comment: When I deleted the `explore.py` file, I got an exception using the `info reg` command. It is still the python libs error

Comment: (gdb) info reg
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF': 
x0             0x0Python Exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF':

Comment: Python Exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF': 
x1             0x0Python Exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'module' object has no attribute 'TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF':

Comment: With `set python print-stack full` it should show the stacktrace of the exception, so you can see in which python file the problem happened.

Comment: @Carlos "Which version of python libs should aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb use": The version your `aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb` was compiled/linked with. What is your exact development platform?

Comment: @ssbssa   File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py", line 207, in __call__
    typename = gdb.types.get_basic_type(val.type).tag
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/types.py", line 34, in get_basic_type
    type_.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF or

Comment: @ ssbssa printing.py is called when using the info reg command, so we can't delete printing.py.

Comment: @Frant ,RK3399, ARM64 architecture, dual-core Cortex-A72 big core+quad-core Cortex-A53 small core structure,

Comment: Simplest workaround would be to add `try:
  rvalue_ref = gdb.TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF
except:
  rvalue_ref = gdb.TYPE_CODE_REF` (properly formatted) before `def get_basic_type` in types.py, and replace all later occurences of `gdb.TYPE_CODE_RVALUE_REF` with `rvalue_ref`.